# Format conversion for TimeStamp to Date

Tags: linux, unix, simpledateformat, datetime-format, sql-timestamp

I need to convert data for all files which have below :

```
TO_DATE('01/31/1970 12:00:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

to simple `31-JAN-1970` format using some automation (bash/Linux/UNIX command should do)

Answer (score 0):

You can use construction like this:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/31/1970 12:00:00 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

BTW consider using POSIX time as this can simplify a lot of operations between dates in shell.